# How to Iterate to all Textboxes for Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic `Textboxes` on my webpage around 50 `Textboxes`.

User can Set Order No. in these `Textboxes`. I have to ensure that only 3 Order No's can be set & no duplicate entries. So User can enter only 1, 2 & 3 in overall textboxes. If he enters 4 somewhere, he should get an error. Rest of the Textboxes have `0` as default value.

How to iterate to all textboxes for checking value not greater than 4 & no duplicate entries & no textbox empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but here's the "straight forward" way:

```
function validateTextBoxes() {
    var values = [];
    var isError = false;
    var atLeastOneFilled = false;

    $('input[type=text]').each(function (idx, elem) {
        var val = $(elem).val();

        if (isNaN(val)) {
            isError = true; // input is not a number
        } else // a number
        {
            var intVal = Number(val);
            if (!isInt(intVal)) {
                isError = true; // not an interger
            } else {
                if (intVal !== 0) // default
                {
                    atLeastOneFilled = true;

                    if (intVal > 3 || intVal < 0) {
                        isError = true; // not in range
                    } else if (values.indexOf(intVal) > -1) {
                        isError = true; // duplicate
                    } else {
                        values.push(intVal);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return atLeastOneFilled && !isError;
}

function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7brjf0wb/).

Comment: I tried the code....When i debugged it doesn't go within foreach loop. Why it doesn't go within foreach?

Comment: The JSfiddle works and it does enter the "each" method. If you are talking about other code, then please show it here and create a fiddle for it as well.

Comment: All is working fine now...just 1 thing remaining..It is allowing duplicate entries...if i enter 2 in two textboxes, it allows..!

Comment: I really dont understand you. You have 50 textboxes and they can handle values that are less than 4, and that can't be duplicates, but all text boxes should be full on the other hand.. I dont really get you.

Comment: It's a kind of Setting...Only 3 Order No's allowed..!

Comment: But how are only 3 non-duplicates allowed while there are 50 fields that cant be empty? The Pigeonhole principle cant allow it. lets say I have 50 fields. Field1: 1, Field2: 2, Field3: 3, Field 4 cant be 1,2,3 and can't be empty...

Comment: The Other Fields I have defaulted them to `0`.

Comment: Ok - I've edited my code to fit your requirements. The fiddle is updated as well.

Comment: Working Perfectly...Thanks for Help..!!